# How to add animated gif to an image sprite?

Tags: css, sprite

I use image / css sprites to optimize a webpage I'm working on, and one of the things thats often needed is an animated loading icon of some kind, which are typically animated .gif files.

Is it possible to add an animated gif to an image sprite (and not have to use gif for the whole sprite)? if so, how do I do that? Do any other image formats support animation?

Comment: Not really possible/worthwhile. Best to stick to one small separate animated GIF for your loading icon. You can have animated PNG files but they're not widely supported afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add an animated gif to an image sprite (and not have
>   to use gif for the whole sprite)?

No, this is not possible. Either the entire sprite sheet is a GIF, or not. you can't mix filetypes in a single sprite. You could instead put all your GIF sprites into a sheet (if their frames are all divisible by one another), and all your PNG/JPG sprites into a second sheet, and use them separately.

> Do any other image formats support animation?

The only other format (that I know of) that supports animation is [APNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG), but it's supported only in Firefox. (Chrome has a buggy extension that supports it.)

Comment: see new edit: "Do any other image formats support animation?"

Comment: and how do you actually add an animated gif to a sprite?

Comment: You'd need some kind of GIF editor (I know [Photoshop can do this](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/build-animated-gifs-in-photoshop/)). Then you'd have to copy the frames to that one GIF file. However, it's probably easier to have your GIFs in separate files. I'm fairly certain that is how sites like Facebook and Google+ handle their GIFs.

Comment: Alright. You might also try Google re: multiple GIFs together. https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=multiple+animations+in+one+gif

Answer (score 0):

I am very early in experimenting with CSS sprites, but for me the biggest (and so far the only) benefit in using them is to reduce amount of request the client needs to send to server.

I haven't tried, but I assume that for the same end result (in that optimization context anyway), one could add the animated gif to the HTML inline with data URI scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Whilst that technique could work to fulfill many of the end scenarios that CSS sprite users are looking for, this topic is still about CSS sprites. I think that complete example of data URI implementation would derail the original topic of "CSS sprites" to "data URIs", which is a large topic in itself. So I think in this case a reference (the wikipedia link) could suffice.